# Population. $58\%$ say "YES" and $42\%$ say "NO" . chances of different opinions.

Tags: probability, statistics

If in a population $58\%$ say "YES" and $42\%$ say "NO" what are the chances that two persons have different opinions?

Thanks :)

Comment: The probability of this to happen is 2*0.42*0.58=0.4872, so 48,72%.

Comment: $2\times(0.58\times 0.42) = 0.4872$

Comment: can you tell me please formula that you used. thanks :)

Comment: If you meet two people you have four possibilities: 1) Both said yes, 2) Both said no, 3) First said yes and second said no, 4) First said no and second said yes. The probability of 1) is 0.58*0.58, the probability of 2) is 0.42*0.42, the probability of 3) is 0.58*0.42 and the probability of 4) is 0.42*0.58. You are obviously interested in the cases 3) and 4).

Answer (score 2):

Let $X,Y$ be $i.i.d.$ Bernoulli random variables with support $\{0,1\}$ and $p=0.58$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}[X=1]=\mathbb{P}[Y=1]=0.58$. We want to find:

$$\mathbb{P}[X\neq Y]=\mathbb{P}[X=0]\mathbb{P}[Y=1]+\mathbb{P}[X=1]\mathbb{P}[Y=0]=2\times 0.58 \times 0.42=0.4872.$$

Comment: I need a formula and a short explication. thanks